# Does firestore charge for reads which does not return data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I checked the documentation on firebase but it does not mention the scenario where for example I have a collection with 100,000 records but the query that I am running does not bring back any result, which means none of the document satisfied the condition. Would I be still charged for checking 100,000 document ?

I currently have a cron job running in a node server which constantly queries the firestore database to look at records which have expired, it the record has expired (this is done by checking the timestamp with the current timestamp) then I am updating a field in the document. I noticed that I am being charged for the reads even though the result set was empty.

Answer (score 8):

According to the [Cloud Firestore billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing):

> “There is a minimum charge of one document read for each query that you perform, even if the query returns no results.”

Answer (score 1):

All of your questions about Firestore billing should be made clear by [reading the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing).  There are many different situations, and you'll possibly need to be aware of all of them, depending on your code.

But to briefly answer your question, you are only charged for documents that are actually delivered to the client, in the case of a simple query.  The size of the collection is not considered at all for the purpose of counting documents read.  Of course, if you have a large collection, you will increase the amount of billing based on its total storage size, including indexes.

Comment: Is this to say that if i have a "users" collection with 10,000 documents in it, each representing an individual user, if I grab the entire collection, it would only count as 1 read, or will it count as X reads, X being the number of documents returned in query

Comment: This will be charged as 10.000 documents reads, because you are reading 10.000 documents, even if you need only 1 query.