# Fetch all documents in collection - Firebase Firestore iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a "users" collection where each document within the collection represents a single user.

If I fetch all documents within the "users" collection, is that considered 1 read to the firebase usage quota or X reads (X being the number of documents within said collection)?

Current code looks like this:

```
static func fetchAllUsers(completion: @escaping([TFUser]) -> Void) {
        var users = [TFUser]()
        
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            snapshot?.documents.forEach({ (document) in
                let dictionary = document.data()
                let user = TFUser(dictionary: dictionary)
                users.append(user)
                
                if users.count == snapshot?.documents.count {
                    completion(users)
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

Any insight on this matter is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When querying a collection, you are billed for each document returned from the query.

If possible, instead of pulling in all of the documents and sorting through them to find the ones that you want, you can use the `.where()` functionality provided by the client SDK.

If you want to save on data usage, since the client SDK does not support partial reads of documents, you can create an HTTPS callable cloud function and only send the desired document data back to the client.

Comment: to quickly sanity check, if I query a collection 1000 times, and each query returns 0 documents, that will be considered 0 reads?

Secondly, can you expand and point me to some documentation regarding your note on "saving on data usage". by using callable cloud functions?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52214213/does-firestore-charge-for-reads-which-does-not-return-data) answer, you are charged for one read per query. Doug Stevenson is the man, [this is a great article on https functions](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/should-i-query-my-firebase-database-directly-or-use-cloud-functions-fbb3cd14118c)